# WPF DataGrid - MS Access Table - Column headings display but not data is pulled

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I followed the information found here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/walkthrough-display-data-from-a-sql-server-database-in-a-datagrid-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

This article is for using SQL server as the source but I'm using Access accdb instead.  This seemed to be the most straightforward article that referenced pulling data. I'm very new to WPF/C# but trying to learn as I think I can build a better interface for a tool that is built in Access right now since there are more UI options and I want to expand a bit outside VBA which I know very well but is a less than ideal language.

Anyhow, below I think is the relevant code. If I preview the data set in designer, I can see it does pull back data into a control that is a data grid itself and it mentions this Fill, GetData()  so maybe there is somewhere I'm supposed to call that.

If I can figure out where/how I'll answer my own question and close this.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="processScheduleGrid" />
```

C#:

```
var query = from ps in dataSet.PROCESS_SCHEDULES                        
                        orderby ps.SCHEDULE_NAME
                        select new { ps.SCHEDULE_NAME, ps.PROCESS_NAME, ps.DAY_OF_MONTH, ps.DAY_OF_WEEK, ps.START_TIME, ps.END_TIME, ps.STATUS, ps.STATUS_TM, ps.PARALLEL, ps.MINUTES_BEFORE_REPEAT, ps.ENABLED, ps.ERR_NUM };
            
            processScheduleGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Did you make sure your query actually returns any records?

Comment: Yes, the query returns records.

Comment: I tried adding this to get it to Fill the dataset table with the data, and it seemed to get me somewhere at least, 
MICRO_BEDataSetTableAdapters.PROCESS_SCHEDULESTableAdapter processSchedulesTableAdapter = new MICRO_BEDataSetTableAdapters.PROCESS_SCHEDULESTableAdapter();
            processSchedulesTableAdapter.Fill(dataSet.PROCESS_SCHEDULES);

Comment: My problem now is that I'm getting an exception on every column where the data is null, and the exceptions were pre-generated.  I just want it to use a null string when anything is null, but I guess I'm going to have to correct the code on everything it pre-generated.  

If there is one thing I don't like (yet) about C#... all this pregenerated code actually makes it much more confusing because while I can understand some of it there is a lot it generates that doesn't mean anything to me yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working with another object model that is a lot more familiar looking to me being used to working in access with both DAO and ADO.  It's more similar to the latter

The revised code is much simpler, and it doesn't do any of the auto-generating that I really am not liking while learning to use C# and Visual Studio more. I think I could have made the above work if I had gone through every column and added handling for nulls but this code handles that with no issue, so it seems like this is the right way to go vs the other object model (System.Windows.Data vs System.Data/System.Data.OleDb) and syntax.

```
 OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(provider);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "PROCESS_SCHEDULES");
            processScheduleGrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["PROCESS_SCHEDULES"].DefaultView;
```